# How to run the Arduino code with a button?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I want to stop the stepper and servo motors by pressing the button once. However, in this code, I need to press and hold for stopping them. How can I change the code and stop them only pressing once? I will be grateful if you can help me about this situation. Thanks in advance.

The Arduino Code:

```
// Include the necessary libraries
#include <AccelStepper.h>
#include <Servo.h>

// Define the pins for the components
int irSensor = 7;
int servo1Pin = 5;
int servo2Pin = 6;
int buttonPin = 2;
#define MP1  8 // IN1 on the ULN2003
#define MP2  9 // IN2 on the ULN2003
#define MP3  10 // IN3 on the ULN2003
#define MP4  11 // IN4 on the ULN2003
 
#define MotorInterfaceType 8 // Define the interface type as 8 = 4 wires * step factor (2 for half step)

// Initialize the components
AccelStepper stepper = AccelStepper(MotorInterfaceType, MP1, MP3, MP2, MP4);//Define the pin sequence (IN1-IN3-IN2-IN4)
Servo myServo1;
Servo myServo2;

bool buttonState = true; // Initialize button state to true

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(irSensor, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP); // Set the button pin mode to input with pull-up resistor
  myServo1.attach(servo1Pin);
  myServo2.attach(servo2Pin);
  
  // Set up the stepper motor
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(1000); // Set the maximum motor speed in steps per second
  stepper.setAcceleration(200); // Set the maximum acceleration in steps per second^2
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin); // Read the button state

  if (buttonState == HIGH) { // If the button is not pressed
    int irValue = digitalRead(irSensor);

    if (irValue == 0) { // If the IR sensor reads 0
      // Run the servos
      myServo1.write(0); // First servo to 0 degrees
      delay(1000); // Wait for the servo to reach 0 degrees
      myServo1.write(180); // First servo to 180 degrees
      delay(3000); // Wait for the servo to reach 180 degrees
      myServo2.write(0); // Second servo to 0 degrees
      delay(1000); // Wait for the servo to reach 0 degrees
      myServo2.write(180); // Second servo to 180 degrees
      delay(3000); // Wait for the servo to reach 180 degrees
    }
    else if (irValue == 1) { // If the IR sensor reads 1
      stepper.setSpeed(500); //Set the motor speed in steps per second
      stepper.runSpeed(); // Run the motor at the set speed
    }
  }
  else { // If the button is pressed
  // Stop the servos and the stepper motor
  myServo1.write(90); // First servo to 90 degrees (stop position)
  myServo2.write(90); // Second servo to 90 degrees (stop position)
  stepper.stop(); // Stop the stepper motor
  }
}
```

I tried the code above.

Comment: You may need a layer to _debounce_ the button: https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/digital/Debounce

Comment: Doing (e.g.) `myServo1.write(0); delay(1000);` seems a bit fragile/racy to me. Can you read back the value? If so, something like: `void svwrite(Servo *sv,int newval) {  sv->write(newval);  while (1) { delay(10); int curval = sv->read(); if (curval == newval) break; } }` would provide more assurance.

Comment: 0___ had a perfectly good answer that was missing a "static" keyword, but they deleted it.

Comment: Is your requirement for the motor to spin until a button is pressed, and then stop. And that's the end of it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two states for tracking the `buttonState` and `motorsRunning`. The button pressing toggle the `motorsRunning` state, and whether the motors are running based on the `motorsRunning` state.

```cpp
bool motorsRunning{true};
int lastButtonState{LOW};

setup() {
  //setup codes
}

loop() {
  int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
    delay(20);
    if (buttonState == LOW) { // button pressed
      motorsRunning = !motorsRunning;    // toggle between True->False->True...
    }
  }
  lastButtonState = buttonState;

  if (motorsRunning) {
    // run the motors
  }
  else {
    // stop the motors
  }
}
```

BTW, you may need to add button debouncing code to improve the reliability of button press. You can take a look at my [simplest button debounce solution](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2021/05/the-simplest-button-debounce-solution/) if you need the code.

Comment: what your code does: If the button is pressed, toggle the variable `motorsRunning`. So pressing the button will toggle this variable millions of times per second. This is not what is requested. You should only toggle the variable when the button transitions from not pressed to pressed and viceversa.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki ops, you are right. I modified the code to add a `lastButtonState`.